# Optimizing react webpack config to production

Tags: reactjs, webpack

My web production webpack config looks like:

```
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const WebpackStrip = require('strip-loader');

module.exports = [
{
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    entry: './ui/moduleTest/entry.js',
    output: { path: __dirname + '/public/compiled', filename: 'mod1bundle.js' },
    module: {
    loaders: [
         { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel-loader', include: /ui/, query: { presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react'] } },
         { test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract( "style", "css!sass") }
     ]
         },
    plugins: [
       new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
       new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ]
   }, 
 { devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
   entry: './ui/moduleTest2/entry.js',
   output: { path: __dirname + '/public/compiled', filename: 'mod2bundle.js' },
   module: {
        loaders: [
             { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel-loader', include: /ui/, query: { presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react'] } },
           ]
   },
   plugins: [
         new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
         new ExtractTextPlugin("console.log"),
         new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ]
    },
   ....
  ];
```

I tried to so many things and I can not make it production ready. The react dev tool tells me that I am using the dev version of react. I am kind of new to webpack. I also need to turn off the console.log messages. Any ideas on how to convert this config into a production ready? I've been reading a lot of things but I have problems to understand. I am using a command like:

```
  webpack --config=webpack.prod.config.js --watch --progress --watch-poll -p
```

to compile my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to take a look at [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/).

Its job is to find instances of a given string, then replace them with some other string. Add this code to your plugins array to configure it to build the production version of React.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
})
```

Then make sure you are using the UglifyJS plugin too and that it comes after the `DefinePlugin` in your config.

This will replace all of the following expressions:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  // do slow development code
}
```

With code that looks like:

```
if ("production" === "development") {
  // do slow development code
}
```

Uglify can recognise this at compile time as an `if` expression that will never be true, and remove the entire statement.

If you want to remove all `console.log` statements, the easiest way is to make it a no op in an initialization file.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  console.log = () => {};
  console.info = () => {};
  // ...
}
```

Make sure this code runs before before any of the files that might have logging statements in.

Comment: but in my code I never used commands like:  
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
       // do slow development code
     }

Comment: Sure, but that's how you switch React into production mode (otherwise it will always be in dev mode).

Comment: I tried plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
 new ExtractTextPlugin("console.log"),
 new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
 }),
 new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'react': JSON.stringify('react-min')
 }), 
 new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()   but no luck, yet. Any other idea?

Comment: Finally I added:   new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env':{
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    })   and all is ok now!!!

Comment: http://dev.topheman.com/make-your-react-production-minified-version-with-webpack/

Comment: I now need to find out how to turn off the console.log messages

Comment: All console log messages?